# Having an issue with ng-class during initial load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a pretty simple task at hand.  Build a list, highlight the active item.

Using ng-class and setting the currently selected item in scope works on a click, but not initially.

What am I overlooking here?  Here's the data.

```
$scope.adminTabs =  [{"name": "Agent"}, 
             {"name": "Agent Queue"},
             {"name": "Skills"}
             ]
```

and here's the click in the controller along with setting the initial value:

```
$scope.adminTabs = adminInfo.adminTabs;
  //Default
    $scope.activeAdminTab = $scope.adminTabs[0].name;
    $scope.loadAdminTab = function(){
            $scope.activeAdminTab = this.tab.name;

    }
```

and finally, the ng-class directive itself in action

```
<ul>
                    <li data-ng-click="loadAdminTab()"
                        data-ng-repeat="tab in adminTabs"
                        data-ng-model = "admin.selectedTab" 
                        data-ng-class="tab.name == activeAdminTab ? 'selected' : '' ">{{tab.name}}</li>
                </ul>
```

Problem is, that first item is never set to use the "selected" class, although the scope variable that drives it is indeed set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer so please don't accept it or vote it up. Only here because I created a code snippet showing the code working:

```js
angular.module('MyModule', [])

.controller('MyController', function($scope) {

  $scope.adminTabs =  [{"name": "Agent"}, 
    {"name": "Agent Queue"},
    {"name": "Skills"}
    ];
  
  $scope.activeAdminTab = $scope.adminTabs[0].name;
  
  $scope.loadAdminTab = function(){
     $scope.activeAdminTab = this.tab.name;
  }
});
```

```css
.selected {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='MyModule' ng-controller='MyController'>
  <ul>
    <li data-ng-click="loadAdminTab()"
        data-ng-repeat="tab in adminTabs"
        data-ng-model = "admin.selectedTab" 
        data-ng-class="tab.name == activeAdminTab ? 'selected' : '' ">{{tab.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Gotta be something externally going on here.  I have a div with an ng-if looking for that selectedTab as well, and it works just fine, only the tab itself doesn't highlight.

Comment: If you look at the li in a dom inspector can you see class='selected'? Also may be worth checking that the css is included correctly - the DOM inspector should also show the style being applied.

Comment: yeah, not adding the class in the inspector unless I click.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is its an issue w/ scope in the ng-repeat.

Try changing:

```
$scope.activeAdminTab = $scope.adminTabs[0].name;
```

and

```
data-ng-class="tab.name == activeAdminTab..."
```

To:

```
$scope.obj = {};
$scope.obj.activeAdminTab = $scope.adminTabs[0].name;
```

and

```
data-ng-class="tab.name == obj.activeAdminTab..."
```

Haven't tested, but this is a common issue I encounter w/ angular ng-repeat scopes; solution might work for you.

Comment: Was so hoping this would work, but apparently using a primitive vs an object isn't the problem.  It just doesn't like me setting the default value the way I am for some reason.